# Prefetching extra fields in a ManyToMany table

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design, django-queryset

I am working with Django on a database that has additional fields on intermediate models. Since it's a big database, I try to optimize the way the data is loaded. But I have a problem with the extra fields of the association table.

Let's take this example from [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) :

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I would like to retrieve, from each entity of the `Group` class, all the entities of the `Person` class and all the fields `invite_reason` or `date_joined`.

To retrieve the persons, it goes fast with the `QuerySet.prefetch_related` attribute that prevents the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects.

```py
groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related('members')
```

However, I did not find a solution to retrieve in a constant access time the extra fields `invite_reason` and `date_joined`.

I tried prefetching `membership_set` or a related name in my variable `groups` but my code doesn't go faster.

```py
# NOT WORKING
groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related('members', 'membership_set')
```

I also tried using a `Prefetch` object with a `queryset` parameter using `select_related` but it didn't work. Everything I've tried to load all the `Membership` data into `groups` at initialization has failed and I end up having a very long runtime retrieving the extra fields from the table.

```py
# TAKES A WHILE BECAUSE NOTHING IS PREFETCHED
for group in groups:
    invite_reason_list = group.membership_set.values_list('invite_reason', flat=True)
    date_joined_list = group.membership_set.values_list('date_joined', flat=True)
```

How do I stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects?

Comment: Approximately how big is the database ? How many rows for these three tables ?

Comment: There are approximately 8,000 rows in Group, 18,000 rows in Membership, and I use other association tables (a group is not only defined by its members, it's also defined by the meeting places etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't write related_name.all() on prefetching, it does not work as expected. you can get the data like this:

```
prefetch_membership_set = models.Prefetch('membership_set',
                                              Membership.objects.only(
                                                  'date_joined', 'invite_reason'))

groups = Group.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch_membership_set)
for group in groups:
    invite_reason_list = []
    date_joined_list = []
    for membership in group.membership_set.all():
        invite_reason_list.append(
            membership.invite_reason
        )
        date_joined_list.append(
            membership.date_joined
        )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! I tried your code and timed the access time on a small subset of my database, and unfortunately this doesn’t seem to make my code’s response faster. If I comment the first line, the response time is **4.8 seconds**. If I add the first line, which is supposed to prefetch the data to speed up the reading of `invite_reason` and `date_joined` for each group in the loop, the response time is **5.5 seconds**. Do you have any idea why ?